# DASHBOARD - Tem como exportar para o Browser?! (Qualquer linguagem pra web)

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3, vba

Como faço para importar esse DASHBOARD feito em VBA no EXCEL, para rodar em browser? Em HTML, CSS, JAVAscript, php... Tanto faz, só quero que rode no browser.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta pergunta está muito ampla. Não contém nenhum tipo de código fonte. Você quer saber se existe algum plugin para PHP que você consiga programar para gerar o mesmo resultado? Ou apenas pegar isso ai e mostrar no browser?

Comment: Desculpe, você tem razão. Ficou muito vago.
Sim, é isso mesmo. Quero saber se existe algum plugin ou alguma ferramenta que eu passe de VBA para PHP e faça tudo que isso faça, no browser...

Oooou, algo que seria útil também: Que eu consiga mover apenas esse dashboard, esse layout, sem a programação em VBA... Pois a programação eu posso fazer depois.

Atualmente o código executa isso(resumidamente):

- Conecta no site automaticamente com login e senha
- Baixa os arquivos em excel
- E joga na tela os dados que baixou

Comment: Amigo, existe uma ferramenta chamada POWERBI da microsoft onde poderia publicar bem fácil isso na WEB. Tem até uma versão gratuita. Veja aqui: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/pt-br/

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta está muito ampla, diante disso vou lhe indicar o melhor caminho a seguir.

Existem formas de converter `Excel` para `HTML` sim, porém isso só é eficiente se estivermos falando de uma planilha em formato de tabela comum, o que não parece ser o seu caso. Você **não** vai conseguir algo automático que seja 100% perfeito, ainda mais se estivermos falando de uma aplicação que tem conexão com banco de dados.

Você irá precisar **reescrever** sua aplicação para alguma tecnologia web, para ter o resultado que deseja muito provavelmente. Uma outra possibilidade, caso essa seja uma aplicação que armazena os dados dentro do próprio arquivo Excel, é manipulá-los usando `Javascript` + `VBScript` no `Front-end`. Caso tenha interesse [clique aqui](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234774/how-to-automate-excel-from-an-html-web-page-by-using-jscript) para ver um exemplo de uso.